# Is GetDate() deterministic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, theory

This is a sort of philosophical question.  In an interview I was present at GetDate was given as an example of a non deterministic function.  I can see why that argument holds water; but it seems a specious argument to me.

To elaborate:
For a given instance in time (within a 100 microsecond band) getdate will return a specific value.

For two computers running to the same clock time (synchronised by a sufficiently accurate clock) they will both return the same value for getdate.

So that is deterministic.

It can be argued that getdate returns different values at different times and so it can not be described as deterministic.

But a sql query "get x from y where primary key equals z" will return the same value for x where z is the same value.  So if the clock is fixed to a certain value then we shall always receive the same value for getdate.

In other words the value of getdate is determined by an external parameter, in exactly the same way as a SQL query that uses a where clause is controlled by that where clause parameter.

So why should we imply that getdate is non deterministic whereas any other variable parameter in a select query which provides a result is described as deterministic.

And just to extend the question; if the data changes then we receive different values to the select query, which we then explain do not affect the deterministicity (to coin a word) as the values have changed in time, just as getdate has.

To expand (as an edit) I could use XP_CmdShell to set a particular date and then immediately run GetDate(); ignoring the vagaries of the speed of the system etc. I would then always get the same answer.  This effectively of negates the argument that  the system date time is not an input as I have modified it via SQL and thus kept the whole process within a SQL controlled loop.

Comment: According to your latter quote:  "Formally, a deterministic algorithm computes a mathematical function; a function has a unique value for any given input, and the algorithm is a process that produces this particular value as output." this then becomes a question as to what is an input.  If I have a box with a fixed date that is not modified then I get a consistent deterministic output.  I see no philosophical difference between a dependency on a manually inputted parameter and one generated by the box itself.

Comment: from MSDN `GETDATE is a nondeterministic function.` reference [`GETDATE()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) under Remarks section.

Comment: Agreed - that is what is says.  And that is how Microsoft treats it.  But that does not address the basic question - it is merely reporting a manner in which Microsoft solved a particular problem for themselves.

Comment: @SimonN What problem?  Why is it a problem that `GETDATE()` is not deterministic?

Comment: It is not a problem that getdate() is not deterministic - I am simply exploring the how deterministic getdate is compared to the general perception of it not being deterministic - hence the philosophical description in the OP

Comment: @SimonN `GETDATE` is not deterministic.  Period.  There are not "levels" of deterministic.  Do you even know why it _matters_ if a function is deterministic or not?

Comment: Yes.   Please see my comment to your post below mentioning Codd.

Answer (score 7):

> For two computers running to the same clock time (synchronised by a sufficiently accurate clock) they will both return the same value for getdate.
>
> So that is deterministic.

No, it's not - deterministic means that the function returns the same value *given the same inputs*.  In this case you have no inputs, but you get different values all the time!  The system clock is not an *input*, it is external state that the function relies upon.

Any query that relies on table data is non-deterministic because it relies on external state.  Examples of deterministic functions are those that do NOT rely on external state, but rely solely on inputs to the function:  `FLOOR`, `DATEADD`, etc.

> if the data changes then we receive different values to the select query, which we then explain do not affect the deterministicity (to coin a word) as the values have changed in time, just as getdate has.

Actually, that proves that the query is NOT deterministic - if a change in external state changes the output of the query.

Comment: - if a change in external state changes the output of the query.But then we get to the ridiculous argument that blasting the server with a shotgun changes the result of the query - so external state (e.g. the server and or the query are extant) affect whether or not the query produces the same results - thus nothing can be deterministic.

Comment: @SimonN At least we can agree that it's a ridiculous argument :)

Comment: Actually we don't.  I was using a Reductio ad absurdum argument to demonstrate that there is a gray area around functions such as getdate.  In so far as you agree that the final part of the extended model is ridiculous then it makes the primary point that there is an issue here.  If we look at Codd's 12 rules it could be argued that ANY external input is not part of the RDBMS system. So what is the difference between a query parameter and an input from the computer which gives a SPECIFIC date time, just as a parameter gives a SPECIFIC value.  Again - this is a philosophical question.

Comment: But `GETDATE()` _has no parameter_ thus has no input.  And the output changes.  Therefore it's not deterministic.  Determinism is a measure of the _algorithm_.  If the server dies, the algorithm can't run, therefore it has no bearing on its determinism.

Answer (score -4):

In my experience it is deterministic. If you

```
SELECT GetDate() from TableX
```

Where TableX has 1mn rows, you would expect the same value returned for all rows, since the evaluation of GetDate does not depend on any value in any of the rows.

Comment: That is not the definition of a deterministic function.  This answer is simply wrong.

Comment: True, but the SQL Statement describes a set of data at the point at which it is executed, and this does not vary during execution, other than with reference to the data in the set. If a SQL statement describing a set takes a long or short time to execute then it should return a set of data that can be fully described at the point of execution, irrespective of the time taken to execute. For practical purposes this is deterministic behaviour. Agree though, its not strictly deterministic.

Comment: "Deterministic" is not some hazy, fuzzy concept.  It is *very* well defined in the database world and very important for optimization purposes.  SQL Server documentation does a pretty good job explaining what it is:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178091.aspx.  D. Stanley did a good job of explaining what it is as well which is why I upvoted that answer.

Comment: Gordon, I'm not arguing about the definition; which as you say and has been discussed here is that GetDate is non-determinisitic, but the OP was discussing the philosophy of it, not the technicality. You are right - it is non-deterministic; as documented. Interestingly in some circumstances this is a real bind (for instance in regression testing) and so GetDate is often replaced with the concept of "myGetDate()" which for regression testing maps into a deterministic date provider rather than the system one. Again; be clear, this is a comment not a challenge to the accuracy of the tech docs.