# Computed column 'BookID' in table 'Books' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a table with computed column for its custom ID column. The format which I want is `BID(The Year)-0000` for example the one like this:

```
BID2017-0001
```

I tried the below t-sql code but I get the non-deterministic error. How can I solve this problem?

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 BookID AS 'BID'+CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) as VARCHAR(4))+ RIGHT ('0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(4)), 4) PERSISTED UNIQUE,
 ISBN VARCHAR(32),
 BookName NVARCHAR(50),
 AuthorName NVARCHAR(50),
 BLanguage VARCHAR(50),
 StaId int,
 StuId int,
 CatNo int);
```

I tried this article too but couldn't solve the issue.
[non-deterministic](http://www.sqldbpros.com/2012/10/computed-column-with-a-date-computed-column-cannot-be-persisted-because-the-column-is-non-deterministic/)

**UPDATE**
Furthermore, I need the series of `'0000'` to be reset back to `'0000'` when the new year starts. For example, The last ID in 2017 is 'BID2017-0932' when the year is changed to 2018 I would like zero series in the ID to be reset to `'0000'` for example `'BID2018-0001'` how can I achieve this ??

Comment: shouldn't it be `BookID VARCHAR(12)` and then when you fill the table you use your string construct?

Comment: That is not the issue. The issue is with the getdate() function which is causing the error.

Comment: So next year... do you want all of your id's to tick over? I doubt it. Write the year to a column in the record when you create the record. Then you can create a calculated column of that _fixed_ (i.e. deterministic) value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Simplest solution**

I would add a `CreateDate` column thus:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Books
ADD CreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL
CONSTRAINT DF_Books_CreateDate
DEFAULT(GETDATE())
GO
```

then I would add computed column thus:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Books
ADD BookID AS  ('BID' + LTRIM(YEAR(CreateDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(ID), 4)) /*PERSISTED*/
GO
```

Comment: I updated the question. Could you help me with this issue? I couldn't figure out how to overcome this problem.

Comment: @ElhamKohestani: this is doable but , first, could you please Nick.McDermaid's comment wrote yesterday "So next year..." ? I don't see any answer to this comment. On topic: I would create another question. Let me know when you have created the new question.

Comment: I have asked a new question here in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45469183/how-to-change-the-seires-of-zeros-in-a-computed-column

Comment: @ElhamKohestani: I'm going to publish my solution in ~20min.

Answer (score 1):

you have `getdate()` in your code which makes the column non deterministic.Removing that will help ..

If you want to know why getdate() is nondeterministic.check here:[Is GetDate() deterministic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23231117/is-getdate-deterministic)..

Excerpt from answer

> deterministic means that the function returns the same value given the same inputs. In this case you have no inputs, but you get different values all the time! The system clock is not an input, it is external state that the function relies upon.

Comment: How can I get the current year. Any other function? As you see I need to have the current year's value inside the id.

Comment: You can't have it both ways. Either you have a persistent computed column or you have the current year as a part of it. I think that's the point of this answer.

Comment: @ElhamKohestani - if you want the current year *at the point in time at which the row was inserted*, rather than the current year *at the point in time of querying*, which I think is quite likely, then you ought to be *storing* the result of `getdate()` in another column (make `getdate()` the default for that column)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever:That worked, you might want to post it as answer