# How to change the series of zeroes in a computed column

Tags: sql-server, database, calculated-columns, computed-field

I am using the below T-SQL to create a table with a computed column which gives me IDs in `'BID(The Year)-0000'`. The issue is that I would like to reset the series of zeros in the ID when the year is changed.For example, the last ID in the table is `BID2017-0923` when the year is changed I want the series to be reset for example `'BID2018-0001'`.

Here is the T-SQL which currently I am using.

```
CREATE TABLE Books
(
    ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    IDCreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT GETDATE(),
    BookID AS ('BID' + LTRIM(YEAR(IDCreateDate)) + '-' + RIGHT('0000' + LTRIM(ID), 4)),
    ISBN VARCHAR(32),
    BookName NVARCHAR(50),
    AuthorName NVARCHAR(50),
    BLanguage VARCHAR(50),
    StaId int,
    StuId int,
    CatNo int
);
```

**UPDATE:**
Furthermore, I would like the ID col to remembers its last id based on the year it has.For example, the last id in the column is `BID2017-0920` when I change the year to 2010, it has to reset the number series for example `BID2010-0001` but when I switch back the year to 2017, I don't want the series to be reset rather I want it to start from `BID2017-0921`.

Comment: You may need to do this using a trigger when rows are inserted.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it while creating the table?

Comment: You can't have duplicate values in your primary key which is effectively what you are asking for here. And what are you going to do when you exceed 9,999 values for a given year?

Comment: For my case it is not going to exceed 9,999

Comment: In the scenario for which I am creating the table the number of records hardly reaches to 1000.

Comment: Even so you are asking for duplicate values in the primary key column which is impossible by definition. You should probably do this in an insert trigger and utilize row_number which you can partition by year.

Comment: And I would be very wary of creating some logic that works today but will break if the system gets more usage than it does today. Limiting to 4 characters like that is really brittle.

Comment: Can you post your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit#1:** I've updated my solution according to latest OP's comments

```
/*
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomSequence (
    Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    Prefix      VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    LastValue   VARCHAR(50) NULL, -- All generated values will have following pattern: PrefixYYYY-SeqvNumber
    LastYear    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT PK_CustomSequence_Name_LastYear PRIMARY KEY (Name, LastYear),
    LastNumber  SMALLINT NULL
);
GO
-- Config OrderSequence 2014
INSERT  dbo.CustomSequence (Name, Prefix, LastValue, LastYear, LastNumber) 
VALUES  ('BookSequence', 'BID', NULL, 2014, 1)
GO
-- Config OrderSequence 2017
INSERT  dbo.CustomSequence (Name, Prefix, LastValue, LastYear, LastNumber) 
VALUES  ('BookSequence', 'BID', NULL, 2017, 1)
GO
*/

-- Generating new seq
    -- IN Parameters
    DECLARE @CustomSequenceName VARCHAR(50) = 'BookSequence'
    DECLARE @Year               SMALLINT = 2017 --YEAR(GETDATE())
    DECLARE @LenOfNumber        TINYINT = 4
    -- End of IN Parameters
    -- OUT Parameters
    DECLARE @GeneratedValue     VARCHAR(50)
    -- End of OUT Parameters

    UPDATE  s
    SET     LastNumber      = IIF(LastValue IS NULL, LastNumber, LastNumber + 1) + IIF(LastNumber = REPLICATE('9', @LenOfNumber), 1/0, 0),
            @GeneratedValue = LastValue = Prefix + LTRIM(@Year) + '-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @LenOfNumber)  + LTRIM(IIF(LastValue IS NULL, LastNumber, LastNumber + 1)), @LenOfNumber)
    FROM    dbo.CustomSequence s
    WHERE   s.Name = @CustomSequenceName
    AND     s.LastYear = @Year
-- End of Generating new seq

SELECT @GeneratedValue
SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomSequence
--> BID2017-0001, BID2017-0002, BID2017-0003, ...
```

Note#1: This solution work with pessimistic concurrency control (default behavior of SQL Server Database Engine)

Note#2: If we are reaching 10000 following piece of code

```
... IIF(LastNumber = 9999, 1/0, 0) ...
```

will raise an exception

```
Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
Divide by zero error encountered.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Note#3: UPDATE statement could be encapsulated into a stored procedure with `@CustomSequenceName VARCHAR(50)` as input parameter and `@GeneratedValue     VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT` as OUT[PUT] parameter.

Note#4: @LenOfNumber allows to customize length of sequential number (default is 4)

**Edit#2:**

UPDATE statement could be replaced with following combination of INSERT + UPDATE statements:

```
SET XACT_ABORT ON
BEGIN TRAN
    IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM dbo.CustomSequence s WITH(HOLDLOCK) WHERE s.Name = @CustomSequenceName AND s.LastYear = @Year)
    BEGIN
        INSERT  dbo.CustomSequence (Name, Prefix, LastValue, LastYear, LastNumber) 
        VALUES  (@CustomSequenceName, @Prefix, NULL, @Year, 1)
    END
    UPDATE  s
    SET     LastNumber      = IIF(LastValue IS NULL, LastNumber, LastNumber + 1) + IIF(LastNumber = REPLICATE('9', @LenOfNumber), 1/0, 0),
            @GeneratedValue = LastValue = Prefix + LTRIM(@Year) + '-' + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', @LenOfNumber)  + LTRIM(IIF(LastValue IS NULL, LastNumber, LastNumber + 1)), @LenOfNumber)
    FROM    dbo.CustomSequence s WITH(HOLDLOCK)
    WHERE   s.Name = @CustomSequenceName
    AND     s.LastYear = @Year
COMMIT
```